# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, interop, c#-2.0

i am getting following Pop Up Message Box when i try to save a transaction in a windows application

> Unhandled exception has occured in your application.If you click Continue the application
>   will ignore this error and attempt to continue. if you click Quit, the application wil
>   close immediately.
>
> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID 
>    {7E4A7632-4A0C-BAB6-AO7DACOA765B} failed due to following error:80040154

Please note i have build my application in x86 environment and my windows application is also
installed in windows xp 32 bit machine.

In my code the above clsid is used for class that was com component and converted in to the Interop Assembly.

Kindly let me know as to how resolve the same on the installed machine.

Comment: You probably need to install that component to the other machine.

Comment: Hi, but we just have dll file in the form interop.classname.dll, where before converting it in to interop assembly it was classname.dll

Comment: Use the vendor's recommended install procedure to get the COM component deployed on the machine.  Or repeat whatever you did to get it installed on your dev machine.  The interop DLL is the non-critical part of the problem, you only have to copy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the misunderstanding is about what the interop assembly does.  You said "converted into", but that is not at all what happened.  The interop is simply the glue required between .Net and COM, like .Net class and function declarations.  It doesn't do any real work - the function calls eventually need to go into the COM library, which has to be properly installed and registered.